# iOS - Issue with reading from a plist

Tags: ios, plist

I'm having an issue with reading from a plist I can't seem to figure.

My plist list looks like this (note i've simplified it for examples sake):

[image]

Then I'm reading code like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ContactDetails" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray* allmyKeys = [myDictionary allKeysForObject:@"Name1"];
```

Any ideas - the issue i keep facing is allmyKeys shows up as containing 0 objects. On debugging myDictionary is correctly populated so not sure why it doesn't work.

Many Thanks

Comment: Sorry its Name1 - i've just wrote it wrong in the description - have corrected.

Comment: And what are you trying to retrieve? If you want all of the keys (`@"Address1"`,`@"Address2"`, etc.) for `@"Name1"`, it would be `[dictionary[@"Name1"] allKeys]`. Or, if you're looking for the whole dictionary object associated with the `@"Name1"` key, it would be `dictionary[@"Name1"]`. The `[myDictionary allKeysForObject:@"Name1"]` looks for values that match `@"Name1"`, not keys that match `@"Name1"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
NSArray* allmyKeys = [myDictionary allKeysForObject:@"Name1"];
```

`@"Name1"` is a **key** in your dictionary, not a value. Even if it were a value, the string `@"Name1"` is a different object from the string with the same value in `myDictionary`, so this call would not do what you expect.

You probably want to access the dictionary by doing

```
NSDictionary *userDetails = myDictionary[@"Name1"];
```